# Change user role by ajax button for one user from list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, roles

I have customer list in page which are output in a loop

```
 <?php
        foreach ($customers as $user){
           ...
        };
        ?>
```

Next to each user, the link "Change role" output in a loop

I have ajax to do action by click

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.ajax-changerole').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: "changerole",
                nonce: ajax_object.changerole_nonce,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });

    })

})
```

I have handler

```
 public function changerole()
    {
        $customers = get_users([
            'role__in' => [Roles::CUSTOMER, Roles::MYROLE]
        ]);

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'changerole')) {
            wp_send_json_error([
                'message' => __("This action is not permitted for you.", domain)
            ]);
        }
        foreach ($customers as $user) {
            if (in_array('customer', (array)$user->roles)) {
                echo $user->set_role('myrole');
            } else {
                echo $user->set_role('customer');
            }
        }
    }
```

Now role changed good by click link but one exception - role change for all customer and I want change for only one - next to which I click on the link

Comment: To begin with then, you need to send the ID of the clicked user in the AJAX request, so that the server knows which one to update.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.ajax-changerole').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: "changerole",
                userId: $(this).attr("user_id"), //You can try that way
                // u must write user id in ajax-changerole element with php - 
                // like this <div class="ajax-changerole" user_id="<?=$user->id?>">
                nonce: ajax_object.changerole_nonce,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });

    })
})
```